# asp.net mvc opening a view in new window without master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am wondering if it is possible to open a view in a new window but without the masterpage defined in the header?  would I just define a separate view?  or is there a better way?
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just create an empty Master page, and pass the name of that Master page when returning a `ViewResult`:

```
return View("MyView", "Empty"); // Use the "Empty" Master page to render the view
```

Comment: Just make sure your empty master page has the same content placeholders and you still define an html & body tag, etc.